# boolean value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, haml

I've declared some simple boolean field in my `model/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :has_car

def  init(age)
 if age > 18
   has_car = true
 else
   has_car = false
 end
   has_car
end
...
```

Then in  my view (`.html.haml` file), I tried to just print the field:

```
...
%li
 - if this_user.has_car
   = "This person has a car"
 - else
   = "This person does NOT have a car"
...
```

For some reason, `this_user.has_car` always evaluates to `false`.
Could anyone tell me what I did wrong here? (I'm very new to Ruby/Rails)

Thanks

Comment: when you are calling `init`?? It doesn't call automatically.. u need to call it..

Comment: Is it possible to assign a default value to `has_car` so that if `init` doesn't get called, `has_car` still has some value?

Comment: `For some reason, this_user.has_car always evaluates to false` :  I think you have `nil` value for `has_car`. To initialize to `true` or `false` u need to call at some point like `before_create` or something. But I am not getting how you are passing `age`.

Comment: You can specify default value.

Comment: How can I do that? Just the same one way would in C? (ie., `int x = 1;`) ?

Comment: So do something like `attr_accessible :name, :has_car = true` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25327/discussion-between-codeit-and-one-two-three)

Answer (score 9):

you can define a method called `has_car?` in the user model

```
# user.rb
def has_car?
  age > 18
end
```

then just use `this_user.has_car?` in your view.

Comment: +1 no need to fiddle with booleans if the statement you're checking already yields a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age, :has_car

  def initialize
    # Everyone does not have a car
    self.has_car = false
  end

  def has_car?
    self.has_car || self.age >= 18
  end

  def purchase_car
    self.has_car = true
  end

  def sell_car
    self.has_car = false
  end
end
```

The initialize method is used when you call `user = User.new` or `user = User.create`.  This method simply sets `has_car` for that instance to false.

You can then ask `user.has_car?` which will return true if the user has a car (they've purchased one) or they are 18 or older.

Because 16 year olds (in some states) can buy cars, you can call `user.purchase_car` to specify that they now own a car.  The `has_car?` method checks the `has_car` database column before checking their `age`.

The `sell_car` method does something similar, but it sets `user.has_car` to false.

Hope this helps, good luck in your `Learn Ruby on Rails` quest!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the method read like this?

```
def init(age)
  if age > 18
    has_car = true
  else
    has_car = false
  end
  return has_car
end
```

Comment: Is `age` and integer and not a string or anything?

Comment: in ruby, the last line is what's always returned so the original method is the same as your answer.